# /dev/sda7: clean, 213012/3170304 files, 1905582/12679168 blocks ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, login

I updated to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and when trying to login into my account or Guest account this error appears and returning me to the login page :

/dev/sda7: clean, 213012/3170304 files, 1905582/12679168 blocks ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. That's not an error message. It's a normal info message.

Comment: The problem that i'm stuck with the login screen and cannot login into my account nor the guest account :/

Comment: I was just letting you know that the message was not an error and had nothing to do with your problem. Lots of different things can cause a login loop. The answers at the other question give the most common solutions.